# Calcular tempo de uso de sistema com MySQL

Tags: mysql

Bom dia,

Tenho um sistema onde a cada 5 minutos que um usuário fica logado, é gerada uma entrada de log no mysql no formato abaixo:

```
+---------+---------------------+
|username | datahora            |
+---------+---------------------+
| manoel  | 2021-09-01 07:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| manoel  | 2021-09-01 07:05:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| manoel  | 2021-09-01 07:10:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| manoel  | 2021-09-01 07:15:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 07:16:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| manoel  | 2021-09-01 07:20:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 07:21:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 07:26:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 07:31:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 07:36:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 09:44:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 09:49:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 09:54:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

Nesse exemplo o usuário manoel começou a usar o sistema as 07:00 dia 21/09/2021 e ficou usado as 07:20.
Nesse meio tempo o usuário joao começou a usar o sistema as 07:16 do mesmo dia e ficou usando as 07:36. Ficou um tempo sem usar e usou de novo de 09:44 as 09:54 do mesmo dia.
Eu preciso fazer uma consulta me retorne um resumo de todas as vezes que algum usou o sistema no formato abaixo:

```
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| usename | entrada             | saida                |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| manoel  | 2021-09-01 07:00:00 | 2021-09-01 07:20:00  |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 07:16:00 | 2021-09-01 07:36:00  |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| joao    | 2021-09-01 09:44:00 | 2021-09-01 09:54:00  |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Já tentei várias consultas mas não consegui fazer dessa forma.
Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar.

Edit:

Eu acabei resolvendo de outra forma.
Adicionei mais uma coluna à tabela com informação de saída do usuário.
A cada intervalo de tempo eu faço atualização do tempo de uso do sistema, caso já exista uma entrada ou insiro uma nova caso não exista.

Comment: Como identificar uma "saída"? Quando o intervalo entre os horários for mais de 5 minutos?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: *"Já tentei várias consultas mas não consegui fazer dessa forma"* e que consultas foram essas? coloca na pergunta pois pode faltar apenas algum ajuste ou se forma uma forma que não dê certo isso vai ajudar outras pessoas que lerem. De qq forma, `MIN` e `MAX` vão retornar os valores que precisa, só usar `GROUP BY` para agrupar por data

Comment: @Woss eu identifico a saída como sendo a última entrada da tabela para um username que não seja maior que 5 minutos da entrada anterior.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Eu usei a consulta abaixo: 

<pre>
select 
 min(datahora), max(datahora), username
from
 registro
group by(registro.username)
</pre>

Mas ela me retorna sempre o primeiro e o último registro de cada username.
Mas aí se um usuario acessou o sistema há dez dias, por exemplo, ele vai me mostrar que entrou há dez dias e saiu hoje.

Comment: como eu comentei, o group deveria ser por data tbm, ou seja, usuario+data senão não agrupar como esperado. Em tempo, edite e pergunta e coloque lá essa query fica melhor e formatada, basta clicar no link "Editar" [ou aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/528397/edit)